# Keras functional api gives error "expected ndim=3, found ndim=4"

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, lstm

I am trying to build a multi-input multi-output model using [keras functional api](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/#multi-input-and-multi-output-models) and I am following their code
but I got that error:

> ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_54: expected
>   ndim=3, found ndim=4

I got that error during creating the lstm_out layer, here is the code:

```
def build_model(self):
    main_input = Input(shape=(self.seq_len, 1), name='main_input')
    #seq_len = 50, vocab_len = 1000
    x = Embedding(output_dim=512, input_dim=self.vocab_len()+1, input_length=self.seq_len)(main_input)

    # A LSTM will transform the vector sequence into a single vector,
    # containing information about the entire sequence
    lstm_out = LSTM(50)(x)
    self.auxiliary_output = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='aux_output')(lstm_out)

    auxiliary_input = Input(shape=(self.seq_len,1), name='aux_input')
    x = concatenate([lstm_out, auxiliary_input])

    # We stack a deep densely-connected network on top
    x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
    x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
    x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)

    # And finally we add the main logistic regression layer
    main_output = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='main_output')(x)

    self.model = Model(inputs=[main_input, auxiliary_input], outputs=[main_output, auxiliary_output])

    print(self.model.summary())
    self.model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='binary_crossentropy',
              loss_weights=[1., 0.2])
```

I thought the problem is with the input_dim in the Embedding layer but I read in the [keras Embedding documentation](https://keras.io/layers/embeddings/) that (input_dim should equal size of vocabulary + 1).

I do not know exactly why I got this, and what is the exact error in my input_dim, and how to solve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input shape for Embedding should be a 2D tensor with shape: (batch_size, sequence_length). In your code snippet main_input is provided which is a 3D tensor. To fix it change the following lines:

```
main_input = Input(shape=(self.seq_len, 1), name='main_input')
<...>
auxiliary_input = Input(shape=(self.seq_len,1), name='aux_input')
```

to:

```
main_input = Input(shape=(self.seq_len, ), name='main_input')
<...>
auxiliary_input = Input(shape=(self.seq_len, ), name='aux_input')
```

It should solve the issue with different dimensions